# iOS App Memory vs Device Memory

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a problem with an iOS app where memory used by the app, as shown in Allocations on Instruments, is completely out of step with the memory being used on the device itself. I'm seeing memory warnings and crashes I can't seem to avoid.

The app is pretty simple in structure. Three UIViewControllers and a UINavigationController. The user starts at the first VC which has a few buttons, navigates to the second VC which has around 20 thumbnail images attached to buttons. On tapping a button the user goes to the third VC which has a  few high resolution images, typically 900 x 600 pixel PNGs.

If I run the app on my iPod Touch or my iPhone 4S, the story in Instruments/Allocations is pretty much the same. It starts at just under 1MB and after looking at around 20 of the high res images, the memory is up to around 1.5MB, but I start to get memory warnings and the app crashes very soon afterwards.

I've checked in the Leaks tool, but there's nothing more that a few kB leaking occasionally.

However, if I look at the Activity Monitor in Instruments its a completely different story. I can see that when the app starts the system allocates around 15MB to it, but as I look at more and more images, the usage continues to increase until its using everything the device has available, at which point I get memory warnings and the app crashes, as does Springboard, and the device goes back to the 'slide to open' screen.

Obviously, my suspicion is that the images are being retained.

I'm using the following to create the images:

```
 layer1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myCGRect];

    UIImage *img1 = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:imgName];

    layer1.image = img1;
    layer1.opaque = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:layer1];
    [img1 release];
    img1 = nil;
```

layer1 is a UIImageView that's a property of the VC. I release it in the dealloc.

But it looks like I'm doing this the wrong way as when I return to VC2 from VC3, VC3 still exists.

So two questions.

1. What should I do about managing the retain/release of the images?
2. Where should I release VC3, and how can I be sure something else doesn't retain it, e.g. an NSTimer or something.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that I wasn't releasing the third view controller, so that every time I navigated back to it, it created a new instance, along with all the images which got retained as well.

The solution was to be more precise in ensuring that I released anything I alloc'd. When I did that I was able to navigate back to the third VC many times without massive memory increase.